# Setting up event mailings to have link to register folks sans entering in details already in their membership record

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration

To my surprise, CiviCRM seems to by default send e-mails to users requesting they fill out details that are already part of their membership record; Name, address, etc. There may be a use case for this, but we are just looking to have a button that can be used (if already logged in, or prompting to login if not) to "Register for event", like other event management software. Is this possible?

Comment: What CMS is this using?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - Good point. Edited tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct these using a Checksum. Instructions are [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/). The actual construction will depend on CMS and on the target form

Comment: Thanks, though to my understanding this functionality has security implications if the e-mail is forwarded. Need the link to prompt for login, before allowing any action/changes to be made against the owners account, or skip this if they are already logged in, in the link opening browser window. P.S If you were to edit your answer to address the aforementioned, but I suggest putting in some contents of the link to prevent link rot?

Comment: Fwd'ing is an issue. A workaround is to have two buttons eg "John renew here" and "Others join/renew here". A workaround (in Drupal) for the latter is to set up a webform asking for email, then send out the checksum in a link to a subsequent webform.

Comment: Thanks. Neither option sounds great, but maybe the solution I have to end up with.

Comment: "Need the link to prompt for login" do you mean all the recipients have a user account? if so why not send them to the profile via a login page (assuming WP has similar to Drupal, namely added something like ?destination=<profile path>. that would then avoid your security concerns

Comment: Looks like it does (https://www.scratchcode.io/after-login-redirect-to-previous-page-in-wordpress/), however then I need bring them to a page which does what the destination should (elect their participation in an event, which the page would only provide confirmation of that action). To prevent someone in the know just taking the destination page out of the e-mailed link and have that action based on not logging in, looks like one can force some pages to be only accessed after logging in, by (ideally) creating a new role for those pages, rather than Editor role in Wordpress default.